# Translated category is not found

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I have a SAP Business One server on one end and a Wordpress with Woocommerce and WPML on the other end.

I clone product categories and products from SAP to Wordpress. The connections between the products, product categories and the languages (English and Hebrew) are made in one script with PHP and MySQL.

After the cloning is done, all the categories, products and their translations look fine in the Wordpress Dashboard. I can switch to the translated product and the translated category without any problems.

When i browse the website, i can view a product and switch between languages for the product, BUT this doesn't work for the categories!

When i try to visit a translated category (from EN to HE) i get 404.
The category title in the URL is the translated one and so it seems like the connection between categories exists, but i cant see the translated category...

I tried:

- Rebuilding the links
- Disabling plugins
- In Woocommerce,the taxonomy hierarchy synchronization is synchronized

Comment: Did you check if there's actually a hebrew entry of your category, in wp backend?

Comment: @ad_on_is yes, all the categories and their translations exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really silly but i forgot to [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the category slug...
Did this for the products but forgot the categories! Ran a quick fix, everything works fine now.